# Finding position through GPS

Tags: android

```
public class WhereamI extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wheream_i);

        LocationManager locationmanager;
        String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

        String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        updatewithnewlocation(location);
        locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
                locationlistener);
    }

    private final LocationListener locationlistener = new LocationListener() {

        private Location location;

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            updatewithnewlocation(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            updatewithnewlocation(location);
        }
    };

    private void updatewithnewlocation(Location location) {
        String latLongString;
        TextView Text1;
        Text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            double alt = location.getAltitude();
            latLongString = "Lat: " + lat + " Lon " + lng + " Altitude "
                    + alt + "feet";
        } else {
            latLongString = "No Location Found: Sorry.";
        }
        Text1.setText("Your Current Position Is \n :" + latLongString);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wheream_i, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have written a code to find the current location of my device through GPS. The problem is most of the times the device does not give any location. But when i make some changes in the code and upload the changes(or launch the app.) to my device it gives the location.
the purpose of this app is to find changes in position and give the long and lat values and even the altitiude. I donot know what is wrong with the app. Can someone hep?

Comment: you are not checking if the best location provider is turned on or not. if it is off then you should turn it on and then get the location.

Comment: initially if you have never have used a gps or network to get your location then you  will always get "No Location Found: Sorry." and to get a location now you have to set 2000 and 10 to 0,0 else you will start getting location after 20 seconds or 5 meter location change.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what provider you use GPS, NETWORK or best, all work on the same principle of getting the location from a local (on the device) cache.

Try this experiment. Change your physical location (move around, about 200m from where you are now) and load google maps, all of a sudden your app will return the correct coordinates too. That is because google maps knows how to trigger a local cache update. The reason it gives you the location after you launch the app is because you are triggering the local cache using `requestLocationUpdate` in your code. It hence gives you the co-ordinates until it gets a new one.